# how to get previous date greather than current value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can following values be obtained using dataframe grouped by the name column, preferably without apply method for performance issue, if possible.

1. previous value greater than current value
2. date at which the previous value was greater than the current value
3. minimum value in the period(the previous date in number 2 ~ the current date)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: kindly provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: if you would put data as text with dataframe then we could resolve it.

Comment: any idea [cummax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) or similar functions - or something like [window.Expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html) but I can't test it on image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single column with numbers can work `expanding window` with `apply` which first works only with one row, next only with 2 rows, next with 3 rows, etc. So working `"window"` is bigger and bigger.

But it works only with one column - so it calculate value but it can't get date.

And it uses `apply` which you don't want but it may work faster then using `for`-loops - but I didn't check it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':  ['01-01','01-02','01-03','01-04','01-05','01-06','01-07'],
    'value': [10, 4, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4],
})

def func(window):
    #print(window)
    mask = (window > window.iloc[-1])
    rows = window[mask]  # all previous values grater then current value 
    value = rows.min()   # minimal value 
    return value

df['prev_gt_curr'] = df.expanding().apply(func)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
    date  value  prev_gt_curr
0  01-01     10           NaN
1  01-02      4          10.0
2  01-03      3           4.0
3  01-04      4          10.0
4  01-05      1           3.0
5  01-06      6          10.0
6  01-07      4           6.0
```

---

**EDIT:**

To work with all columns I have no other idea but `for`-loop

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':  ['01-01','01-02','01-03','01-04','01-05','01-06','01-07'],
    'value': [10, 4, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4],
})

results = []

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    print('---')
    window = df[['date','value']][:i+1]
    
    mask = window['value'] > window['value'].iloc[-1]
    rows = window[mask]

    if rows.size:  # if rows.size > 0:
        index = rows['value'].idxmin()
        values = rows.loc[index].tolist()
        minimal = window['value'][index:i+1].min()
        values.append(minimal)
    else:
        values = [None, None, None]

    print('values:', values)
    results.append(values)
    
df[['prev_date', 'prev_value', 'min_value']] = results

print(df)
```

Result:

```
    date  value prev_date  prev_value  min_value
0  01-01     10      None         NaN        NaN
1  01-02      4     01-01        10.0        4.0
2  01-03      3     01-02         4.0        3.0
3  01-04      4     01-01        10.0        3.0
4  01-05      1     01-03         3.0        1.0
5  01-06      6     01-01        10.0        1.0
6  01-07      4     01-06         6.0        4.0
```

Comment: Many thanks! I will put text data as you recommended. I can also loop on the name columns with your code.